# Cannot display checkbox in grid using Ext.grid.CheckColumn Extjs Version 2.2

Tags: extjs, extjs-grid, extjs2

When I am trying to add a check column to the grid using below codes

```
this.entitlementColModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([new Ext.grid.RowNumberer(), {
        header : 'CIF',
        dataIndex : 'cif',
        width : 80,
        editor : new Ext.form.TextField({
                    maxLength : 20,
                    allowBlank : false
                }),
        editable : true
    }, new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
        header: 'AML',
        dataIndex: 'amlActive',
        resizable:false,
        width: 25,
        onMouseDown : function(e, t){}
    })]);
```

Getting the below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ext.grid.CheckColumn is not a constructor
```

Also tried `xtype: 'checkcolumn',`

It is also not working. I can't upgrade ext version currently. Is there any replacement for this method in version 2.2 ?

Comment: You can refer this link. https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259256-check-box-column-view-in-grid-Panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use action column 
{
xtype: 'checkcolumn', 
text: 'Active', 
dataIndex: 'active'
}